# What is a rotation matrix and how to implement it?

Tags: matrix, image-processing, information-retrieval, rotation

In [Revisiting the VLAD Image Representation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2502171) the authors introduce Local Coordinate System, i.e. they:

> we learn off-line (for each visual word) a rotation matrix Qi from training descriptors mapped to this word.

So they obtain `k` (i.e. the number of visual words, or k-means parameter) rotation matrices.

My question is: **how do you compute a rotation matrix given a set of descriptors?**

Comment: I think a rotation matrix is simply a matrix that rotates the x and y axes.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Reading more accurately the paper, I think that they mean a simple PCA: "This is simply obtained by learning a “local”
PCA per Voronoi cell of the partitioned feature space." Do you know any good solution for PCA in c/c++?